# Python text file to Json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, txt

Hey all trust that you're well, I'm currently trying to convert a **.txt** file to a **.json** file with a certain output(**Desired Output**).

Using a loop to store multiple keys within a single array. If I run it again I would like to store a second set of keys within the array you may find the example below(**Desired Output**)  I'm open to other methods, below is how I attempted to achieve this result.

**Code:**

the input for the **.txt** file

```
i = 1

while i < 6:

    user = input("Enter username: ")

    with open("new.txt", "a") as n:
        n.write('{} {}\n'.format(f"username{i}", f"{user}"))
        i += 1
```

**Output:**

the output in the **.txt**

```
user1 just
user2 serves
user3 as
user4 an
user5 example
```

**Convert to JSON:**

```
import json

files = 'new.txt'

dict = {}

with open(files)as f:
    for file in f:
        #readlines from file and trim spaces to get valid words only
        key, desc = file.strip().split(None, 1)
        dict[key] = desc.strip()

otfile = open('new1.json', 'w')
json.dump(dict, otfile, indent=4)
otfile.close()
```

**Output:**

the output in the **.json**

```
{
    "user1": "just",
    "user2": "serves",
    "user3": "as",
    "user4": "an",
    "user5": "example"
}
```

**Desired Output:**

Output I would like to receive

```
[
    {
        "user1": "just",
        "user2": "serves",
        "user3": "as",
        "user4": "an",
        "user5": "example"
    },

    {
        "user1": "just",
        "user2": "serves",
        "user3": "as",
        "user4": "an",
        "user5": "example"
    }
]
```

Comment: Why the value of `”user1“` is  `"alaink_SPANic"`? Where did you get it

Comment: Please try to specify what exactly you are looking for along with sample input and output. Thanks

Comment: @CN-LanBao my apologies it has been updated

Comment: @SmitParmar please read over it carefully as it has been stated.

Comment: Why can't you write it as a JSON already ? Why taking a pain of conversion! ?

Comment: @Kris trust that you're well not sure how?

Comment: A dictionary is something which stores key to values. In your for loop, if you keep writing same keys again and again, its gonna replace the existing keys - leading to you get a single dict. And I'm quite sure how it is to be done.

Comment: @Kris appreciated, may you please provide an example?

Comment: You can build a list of two dicts and then `json.dump` it.